# How do I set $scope value from $rootScope variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I have the following code in a file.jade file attach to a controller, fileCtrl

file.jade

```
.....
label(for='id') Id: 
input(ng-model='form.id', name='id')
p
....
```

fileCtrl

```
...
  $scope.submitMain = function ( path ) {
      $http.post('/api/submitMain', $scope.form).
      success(function(data) {
        alert("Submit Main Data: " + data);
        $rootScope.id = data;
        $location.path(path);
      });
  };
....
```

path points to file1.jade, which has the same id field and it is attached to file1Ctrl

file1.jade

```
.....
label(for='id') Id: 
input(ng-model='form.id', name='id')
p
....
```

file1Ctrl

```
$scope.form.id = $rootScope.id;
```

For some reason, the $rootScope id set in Filectrl, is not setting the form.id value in file1Ctrl even tho the value is correct in both places.

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Melroy

Comment: why are you using $rootScope ?

Comment: how else can this be achieved.

Comment: The success callback is async, so your $rootScope.id may be undefined within file1Ctrl on init load. You could $watch it and then update $scope.form.id.

Comment: with a service. You could broadcast events, etc

Answer (score 0):

As SergeL said, you will need to do a $watch if you want to pass it through the $rootScope. A $watch watches the given expression for changes and fires a script when it does and can be used on any scope.

```
$rootScope.$watch('id', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if (newVal !== undefined) {
        $scope.form.id = newVal;
    }
});
```

Note that the watch will trigger on initiation with an undefined value, which is why you might want to check to make sure it has a value before using it.

---

However, using the $rootScope might not be the best way since you need the watch, and in larger projects where you often need to share data between controllers you might end up with a ton of stuff in the rootScope, making conflicts a very real possibility. A better way is to use a service to share information.

Services in Angular are singletons, they only exist in one instance, meaning that if two controllers use the same service they share the same data. You would define a service for sharing data something like this:

```
.factory('IdStorage', [function() {
    return {};
}])
```

This will create a service which is essentially just an object, and since services only exist in one instance that object will be shared between anything using the service. So in you callback you can then do:

```
IdStorage.id = data;
```

And in the controller you do:

```
$scope.form.id = IdStorage;
```

Since they both reference the same object (since it is a singleton) they always be the same. Since IdStorage is just an objecty you could store more information in it if you wanted to. And since you can create multiple such services if you need to share different things across the app, you don't run the risk of conflicts like you do if you dump everything into the $rootScope.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with rootscope. However, I will try your solution too